# Wordpress Widget - Option Checkbox to show html if checked

Tags: php, wordpress

***How do I create a widget with checkbox values that contain html code if checked?**

i.e.The HTML code to be placed in the value

```
<div class="subicon"><img class="icon" src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/images/icon1.png"> <p class="avasub">random text</p></div><img class="hr2" src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/images/hr.png">
```

Widget code below without the html above - (Works fine)

```
 <p>
    <label>Checkbox Group</label><br />
    Value 1 <input id="check_array_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][check_array][1]" type="checkbox" <?php if($check[1]){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="one" /><br />
</p>
```

When I add the html as the value instead of the word one or random text, it doesn't show properly.

```
 <p>
    <label>Checkbox Group</label><br />
    Value 1 <input id="check_array_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][check_array][1]" type="checkbox" <?php if($check[1]){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="<div class="subicon"><img class="icon" src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/images/icon1.png"> <p class="avasub">random text</p></div><img class="hr2" src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/images/hr.png">" /><br />
</p>
```

===== Widget Code Used - output shows all checked values except for 1st check-box ======

```
function jad_simple_widget($args, $widget_args = 1) {

    extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );
    if ( is_numeric($widget_args) )
        $widget_args = array( 'number' => $widget_args );
    $widget_args = wp_parse_args( $widget_args, array( 'number' => -1 ) );
    extract( $widget_args, EXTR_SKIP );

    $options = get_option('simple_widget');
    if ( !isset($options[$number]) ) 
    return;

    $title = $options[$number]['title'];        // single value
    $text = $options[$number]['text'];      // single value
    $check = $options[$number]['check'];        // multi value
    $radio = $options[$number]['radio'];        // single value
    $select = $options[$number]['select'];  // single value
    $textarea = $options[$number]['textarea']; // single value

    echo $before_widget; // start widget display code ?>


        <ul>
        <?php foreach($check as $value){ ?>
            <li><?=$value?></li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>


<?php echo $after_widget; // end widget display code

}


function jad_simple_widget_control($widget_args) {

    global $wp_registered_widgets;
    static $updated = false;

    if ( is_numeric($widget_args) )
        $widget_args = array( 'number' => $widget_args );           
    $widget_args = wp_parse_args( $widget_args, array( 'number' => -1 ) );
    extract( $widget_args, EXTR_SKIP );

    $options = get_option('simple_widget');

    if ( !is_array($options) )  
        $options = array();

    if ( !$updated && !empty($_POST['sidebar']) ) {

        $sidebar = (string) $_POST['sidebar'];  
        $sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();

        if ( isset($sidebars_widgets[$sidebar]) )
            $this_sidebar =& $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar];
        else
            $this_sidebar = array();

        foreach ( (array) $this_sidebar as $_widget_id ) {
            if ( 'jad_simple_widget' == $wp_registered_widgets[$_widget_id]['callback'] && isset($wp_registered_widgets[$_widget_id]['params'][0]['number']) ) {
                $widget_number = $wp_registered_widgets[$_widget_id]['params'][0]['number'];
                if ( !in_array( "simple-widget-$widget_number", $_POST['widget-id'] ) ) // the widget has been removed.
                    unset($options[$widget_number]);
            }
        }

        foreach ( (array) $_POST['simple-widget'] as $widget_number => $simple_widget ) {
            if ( !isset($simple_widget['title']) && isset($options[$widget_number]) ) // user clicked cancel
                continue;

            $title = strip_tags(stripslashes($simple_widget['title']));
            $text = strip_tags(stripslashes($simple_widget['text_value']));             
            $check = $simple_widget['check_array'];
            $radio = $simple_widget['radio_value'];
            $select = $simple_widget['select_value'];
            $textarea = $simple_widget['textarea_value'];

            // Pact the values into an array
            $options[$widget_number] = compact( 'title', 'text', 'check', 'radio', 'select', 'textarea' );
        }

        update_option('simple_widget', $options);
        $updated = true;
    }

    if ( -1 == $number ) { // if it's the first time and there are no existing values

        $title = '';
        $text = '';
        $check = '';
        $radio = '';
        $select = '';
        $textarea = '';
        $number = '%i%';

    } else { // otherwise get the existing values

        $title = attribute_escape($options[$number]['title']);
        $text = attribute_escape($options[$number]['text']); // attribute_escape used for security
        $check = $options[$number]['check'];
        $radio = $options[$number]['radio'];
        $select = $options[$number]['select'];
        $textarea = format_to_edit($options[$number]['textarea']);
    }

    print_r($options[$number]);
?>
<p><label>Widget Title</label><br /><input id="title_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][title]" type="text" value="<?=$title?>" /></p>
<p><label>Text Field</label><br /><input id="text_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][text_value]" type="text" size="30" value="<?=$text?>" /></p>
<p>
    <label>Checkbox Group</label><br />

        Value 1 <input id="check_array_1" name="simple-widget1" type="checkbox"  value='<div class="subicon"><img class="icon" src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/images/icon1.png"> <p class="avasub">random text</p></div><img class="hr2" src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/images/hr.png">' /><br />  <!-- Proper Enclosing of value done -->
        Value 2 <input id="check_array_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][check_array][2]" type="checkbox" <?php if($check[2]){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="Two" /><br />
    Value 3 <input id="check_array_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][check_array][3]" type="checkbox" <?php if($check[3]){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="Three" /><br />
    Value 4 <input id="check_array_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][check_array][4]" type="checkbox" <?php if($check[4]){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> value="Four" />

</p>
<p>
    <label>Radio Field</label><br />
    Yes <input id="radio_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][radio_value]" type="radio" <?php if($radio == 'yes') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="yes" />
    No <input id="radio_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][radio_value]" type="radio" <?php if($radio == 'no') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="no" />
</p>
<p>
    <label>Select Menu 
    <select id="select_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][select_value]">
        <option <?php if ($select == 'One') echo 'selected'; ?> value="One">Value 1</option>
        <option <?php if ($select == 'Two') echo 'selected'; ?> value="Two">Value 2</option>
        <option <?php if ($select == 'Three') echo 'selected'; ?> value="Three">Value 3</option>
        <option <?php if ($select == 'Four') echo 'selected'; ?> value="Four">Value 4</option>
    </select>
    </label>
</p>
<p><label>Textarea</label><br /><textarea id="textarea_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][textarea_value]" type="text" cols="30" rows="4"><?=$textarea?></textarea></p>
<input type="hidden" name="simple-widget[<?php echo $number; ?>][submit]" value="1" />

<?php
}


function jad_simple_widget_register() {
    if ( !$options = get_option('simple_widget') )
        $options = array();
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'simple_widget', 'description' => __('Test widget form'));
    $control_ops = array('width' => 400, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'simple-widget');
    $name = __('JAD Simple Widget');

    $id = false;

    foreach ( (array) array_keys($options) as $o ) {

        if ( !isset( $options[$o]['title'] ) )
            continue;

        $id = "simple-widget-$o";
        wp_register_sidebar_widget($id, $name, 'jad_simple_widget', $widget_ops, array( 'number' => $o ));
        wp_register_widget_control($id, $name, 'jad_simple_widget_control', $control_ops, array( 'number' => $o ));
    }




    if ( !$id ) {
        wp_register_sidebar_widget( 'simple-widget-1', $name, 'jad_simple_widget', $widget_ops, array( 'number' => -1 ) );
        wp_register_widget_control( 'simple-widget-1', $name, 'jad_simple_widget_control', $control_ops, array( 'number' => -1 ) );
    }
}
```

add_action('init', jad_simple_widget_register, 1);

?>

Comment: Just as an fyi Wordpress has a handy function called [checked()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) that will do the checked = checked for you

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid, try surrounding your value= in single quotes instead of double quotes as you are using double quotes inside the value content thus generating errors as it see the " as the end of the value and then random characters after that.

```
value='<div class="subicon"><img class="icon" src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/images/icon1.png"> <p class="avasub">random text</p></div><img class="hr2" src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/images/hr.png">'
```

instead of

```
value="<div class="subicon"><img class="icon" src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/images/icon1.png"> <p class="avasub">random text</p></div><img class="hr2" src="http://www.sitename.com/wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/images/hr.png">"
```

Looking at the syntax highlighting here will show you where it keeps breaking your value when it comes to double quotes.

Comment: I found this worked but the url is doubled when it's trying to find the picture...i.e. http://www.sitename.com/http://www.sitename.com

Comment: The code I have shown cannot produce that output. unless you have made a mistake updating sitename.com to your own domain name and pasted it in twice.